# C string array bubble sort returns the input as output

Tags: arrays, c, string, swap, bubble-sort

in my function I am given a string array where it needs to be sorted via a specific ruleset which is also given - the main function works and the rule comparison ones work as well but the bubble sort keeps returning the input as output and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap(char** s1, char** s2) 
{
    char** temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}
main()
{
    int i, j; 
    char** arr_of_strings = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));//I allocated the array 
    arr_of_strings[0] ="wonder_woman";//with malloc and loops originally.
    arr_of_strings[1] ="batman";
    arr_of_strings[2] ="superman";
    for (i = 0; i <2; i++)//the bubble array process:
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3 - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(arr_of_strings[i], arr_of_strings[j]) > 0) 
            {
                swap(&arr_of_strings[j], &arr_of_strings[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
     printf("The sorted strings are:\n"); //printing the function
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr_of_strings[k]);
    }

}
```

output example:

```
The sorted strings are:
wonder_woman
batman
superman
```

Comment: For comparison: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: Please explain 2 things (1) in what way do you want to sort your strings? (2) in the 2nd `for` loop inside condition there is `i < 2` while you took the example size as `3`, why?

Comment: @MukulKumar 1- depends on user input, in the original code it was either letter diversity or lexicogrpahical order, 2- the bubble sort is a modified one from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/ in the program the user is supposed to input n, so I arbitrarily chose n=3 and modified values accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your swap function' or the way you call it.
anyway, this implementation works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 3

int main()
{
    int i, j; int n=SIZE; //n is a user input in the original program.
    char temporary_string[32];
    char* arr_of_strings[SIZE];
char* temp = NULL;

//input data
for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
{
    scanf("%s", temporary_string);
    arr_of_strings[l] = malloc(((strlen(temporary_string) + 1) *sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(arr_of_strings[l], temporary_string);
    temporary_string[0] = '\0';
}

//the actual sort
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr_of_strings[j], arr_of_strings[j + 1]) > 0) //simplification
        {
           //swap
           temp = arr_of_strings[j];
           arr_of_strings[j] = arr_of_strings[j + 1];
           arr_of_strings[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

printf("The sorted strings are:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s\n" , arr_of_strings[i]);
}
 // free allocated memory
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     free(arr_of_strings[i]);
 }
}
```

I hope it helps, if you have quastions I would be happy to answer =)

Answer (score 0):

check this lines, compairing **i with j** , but **swapping j and j+1**

```
if (arr_of_strings[i]> arr_of_strings[j]) //simplification 
  {
    swap(&str_arr[j], &str_arr[j + 1]);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! the correction doesn't solve the output problem but it prevents other ones

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap` function doesn't actually swap the items pointed to by its parameters. Change it to:

```
void swap(char** s1, char** s2) 
{
    char* temp = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = temp;
}
```

Also, your `main` function is comparing non-adjacent items but swapping adjacent items, so it doesn't sort properly.  Change the relevant part of the code to:

```
            if (strcmp(arr_of_strings[j], arr_of_strings[j + 1]) > 0) 
            {
                swap(&arr_of_strings[j], &arr_of_strings[j + 1]);
            }
```

to sort in ascending order.

The bubble sort can be optimized by keeping track of the position of the last swapped item and finishing the sort after a pass that does not swap any items:

```
    i = 3; // sorting first 3 items
    while (i > 1)
    {
        int last = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(arr_of_strings[j], arr_of_strings[j + 1]) > 0) 
            {
                swap(&arr_of_strings[j], &arr_of_strings[j + 1]);
                last = j + 1;
            }
        }
        i = last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap` function doesn't do anything.

It is similar to this function supposed to swap two ints:

```
void swap(int a, int b)
{
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

If you call it like this:

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
swap(a,b);
```

a and b still contain the same values.

This is the correct code for your `swap`:

```
void swap(char** s1, char** s2)
{
  char *temp = *s1;
  *s1 = *s2;
  *s2 = temp;
}
```